# CSS to reduce spacing in list item with wrapped text

Tags: word-wrap, css

I made this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wNf9R/1/) to show my problem.  I have a list and I need to set a negative margin to overlap the list items.

The issue comes when the text is so long that it wraps itself and I can't see how to change the margin of that particular line to make it the same as the rest of the items.  Line-height does not seem to do the trick.  Do you have any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an option to put line-height to the li instead of using negative margin?

http://jsfiddle.net/wNf9R/6/

Or you could set your a's to display:block, apparently the line-height is ignored for a-elements? (i'll leave the explanation to someone else :-)

http://jsfiddle.net/wNf9R/9/

Comment: It works indeed.  And to think I tried almost every other combination with the margin property :P  Thanks to everyone for replying.

Answer (score 1):

Wrapped it around with `div` and gave smaller `line-height`

See http://jsfiddle.net/wNf9R/8/

Answer (score 0):

If all you're trying to do is make the spacing between the lines consistent (i.e., you are okay with the wrapping), then line-height should indeed work.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UWCSS/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `line-height` property in conjunction with specialized `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` properties to even out the intra and inter-element spacing: http://jsfiddle.net/T3NM8/